# The request was rejected because its size

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Tengo el siguiente código en mi controlador el cual se encarga de cargar un cliente con una foto.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/form")
public String guardar(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cliente") ClienteEntity cliente, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus sesion) { 


if (result.hasErrors() || foto.getSize() > 5242880L) {
            LOG.info("La foto pesa " + foto.getSize());
            return "form";
        } else {
             //...
        }

}
```

En mi application.properties tengo lo siguiente

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=5MB
```

De modo que no se puedan subir imágenes con un peso mayor a 5MB, pero cuando lo hago me salta dos veces la misma excepción, la cual es la siguiente

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (10506931) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (5242880)

He probado usar un try-catch e incluso la validación con el if pero mi programa no llega a entrar al controlador y no puedo así realizar alguna acción que evite que salte la excepción.

**EDIT**

En *[esta pagina](http://www.kscodes.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-max-size-validation/)* encontré el siguiente código, ya no me salta la excepción pero tampoco me redirige a mi vista error

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MultipartException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleFileUploadException(MultipartException mpex, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView modelAndVew = new ModelAndView("error");
        modelAndVew.addObject("errorMsg", mpex.getMessage());
        return modelAndVew;
    }
```

En la consola me salen los warning del size

> 2018-03-01 11:45:08.157  WARN 13880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (10506931) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (5242880) 2018-03-01 11:45:09.148  WARN 13880 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   exception caused by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (10506931) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (5242880)

Y Chrome me arroja un *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit2**

Agregue Apache Tomcat como servidor ya que no tenia ninguno seleccionado.

En el *multipart-config* tengo lo siguiente

```
<multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Y en el controlador agregue nuevamente esto

```
if(foto.getSize() >= 5242880L) {
            LOG.error("---------------------- LA FOTO PESA DEMASIADO ----------------------");
            return LISTAR;
        }
```

Pero aun así no entra a mi if, de modo que no hace la dirección y me salta el *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET* de Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He logrado solucionarlo: La respuesta siempre estuvo delante de mis ojos y en estas dos lineas

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=5MB
```

Si el tamaño de la foto supera en tamaño a lo especificado en ***spring.http.multipart.max-request-size*** arrojara el *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET* y dejara de ejecutarse el resto del código.

Por lo que he cambiado lo anterior por esto

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

Y ahora todo funciona correctamente, siempre y cuando la foto no sea mayor a 50MB o el valor especificado.

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones hermano :D! Ahora toca esperar 24 horas para marcar la respuesta como aceptada y santo remedio, ayudas a mejorar la salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 1):

El error que se está lanzando se produce porque el archivo supera el tamaño máximo definido en la configuración del Tomcat, por eso la petición no está llegando al controlador.
Puedes editar el archivo `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`, de acuerdo a tus necesidades, que se ecuentra en el directorio donde tienes Tomcat instalado. Este archivo tiene la siguiente sección:

```
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0<</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Los valores están expresados en bytes. En tu caso por el mensaje de error el archivo que estabas intentando subir pesaba 10506931 bytes, por lo que si quieres que el tomcat permita su subida deberías de configurarlo con un valor superior. Entonces la petición llegaría al controlador spring, donde la validación de los 5MB debería de fallar.

Comment: Hola. Quizas no explique bien mi problema. Yo quiero que el tamaño maximo de la imagen sea de 5MB, y que si se intenta mandar algo mayor me rediriga a una paguina llamada "error". Pero como explico a partir del momento en que edité la publicacion, esto no sucede.

Comment: Creo que sí que te he entendido. Vuelve a leer mi respuesta. Deberías de aumentar en la configuración del Tomcat la limitación que tienes actualmente (5 MB) a 20MB por ejemplo, para que el Tomcat deje pasar la petición que estás haciendo con el archivo de 10MB. Después de esto puedes deshacer la edición que hiciste de añadir el `@ExceptionHandler`. Y entonces la petición debería de llegar a tu controller de Spring y en la línea `foto.getSize() > 5242880L` devería de devolverte un true.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta